# Còmo hacer un saltó de Linea en python?

Tags: python

```py
nombre = pepe
apellido = perez
print(nombre,apellido)

#pepe,perez
```

Como debo hacer para qué imprima

```
Pepe
Pérez
```

Comment: Usa el carácter de salto de línea `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes establecer el parámetro **sep** de [`print`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#print) a un salto de línea. Así:

```
print("Pepe", "Perez", sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo para introducir salto de lineas hay un carácter especial que es:

```py
\n
```

Lo Unico que tendrias que hacer seria.
`print(nombre+"\n"+appellido)`
Listo

**toca la flechita de arriba para apoyar esta respuesta :).**

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira este ejemplo te servira de referencia, pruebalo con tu ejercicios

Comment: El código va como texto. Si pones una imagen, el texto no se puede copiar y Google no indexara tu respuesta, perdiendo tu oportunidad de alcanzar fama y gloria.